# MYSQL Query Error Every Time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am attempting to use a drop-down list to pull Pokémon info back from a database that I've uploaded, and I keep getting the following error:

> No Pokemon was requestedDatabase access failed: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pokemon_name =
>   SELECT * FROM pokemon_info' at line 1

I have a database currently with the headings:

id | pokemon_name | height | weight | gif

I literally can't figure out why... My processing code is as follows;

```
// CODE TO QUERY DATABASE TO GO HERE

// Capture form data, if anything was submitted

if (isset($_POST['pokemon_submit'])) {
    $pokemon_submit = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['submit']);

    // create the SQL query

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pokemon_info where pokemon_info=$pokemon_submit"; 

    // query the database

    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);

    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

    if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

    // if there are any rows, print out the contents

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= "Pokemon: " . $row['pokemon_name'] . ", Gif: " .

$row['gif'] . "<br />";
    }

    else {
        $output = 'Well, you must have invented a new Pokémon, cause it is not on this website!';
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else {
    $output = 'No Pokemon was requested';
}

// CODE TO QUERY END

}

// Close connection!
// YOUR CODE HERE BIT end

echo $output;

$output = '';

mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);

$query = "WHERE pokemon_name = $pokemon_submit SELECT * FROM pokemon_info"; 

$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$output .= "Pokemon: " . $row['pokemon_name'] . ", Gif: " .

 $row['gif'] . "<br />";

}

mysqli_free_result($result);

echo $output;
```

I have now amended thanks to your help, and it's saying that no Pokémon was requested.

The basic idea of this is to have a main page with a drop-down list of pokemon. When a user selects from the list, the information stored in my database about that specific pokemon is displayed.

The drop-down list is linked directly to the pokemon_name column in my database. I don't understand why it's coming back as though nothing is selected?

Thank you all SO much for your help, I'm learning much more here than trawling through forums.

Comment: is that your query? "$query = "WHERE pokemon_name = $pokemon_submit SELECT * FROM pokemon_info";" Is not twisted?

Comment: `clean_string` sounds ripe for sql injection

Comment: `$query = "WHERE pokemon_name = $pokemon_submit SELECT * FROM pokemon_info"; ` makes no senese

Comment: You probably want some conditional WHERE building the query but it needs more work.You have to know waht you want.

Comment: I added a comment on the answer I gave please check it out and see if it assists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one issue(s)

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pokemon_info where pokemon_name=$pokemon_submit";
```

if pokemon_submit is a number - it is ok. If it is a string then you need
`$query = "SELECT * FROM pokemon_info where pokemon_name='$pokemon_submit'";`
notice the single quotes.

```
$query = "WHERE pokemon_name = $pokemon_submit SELECT * FROM pokemon_info";
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
```

I have no clue what you're trying here?  I know of no SQL statements begin with "WHERE"

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE pokemon_name = $pokemon_submit SELECT * FROM pokemon_info
```

is not a valid query.

If you want to select the pokemon $pokemon_submit from pokemon_info, what you do is this;

```
SELECT * FROM `pokemon_info` WHERE `pokemon_name` = '$pokemon_submit'
```

The WHERE comes after SELECT. More on the [doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

I'd also look into verifying data before putting it into the query, OOP approach to MySQLi and general SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of WHERE pokemon_name = $pokemon_submit SELECT * FROM pokemon_info try altering your query to something like ...

```
WHERE pokemon_name in $pokemon_submit SELECT pokemon_name FROM pokemon_info
```

The second part of your query is returning multiple results. ie..... Select * from pokemon_info.

So we refine that to get only the pokemon names back ie..

```
select pokemon_name from pokemon_info
```

And the first part of the query will only want names where the name matches any of the results from the second part of the query

Your full query should look something like

```
select * from pokemon_info WHERE pokemon_name in $pokemon_submit SELECT pokemon_name FROM     pokemon_info
```

or in short

```
select * from pokemon_info where pokemon_name = $pokemon_submit
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That's helped me to get rid of the initial error, but now it's simply saying that no pokemon has been selected. I have a drop-down menu on a page that is linked to the processing page above with the list of 'pokemon_names' showing. When one of those names is selected, I'd like it to bring the info up in my database for that specific pokemon if that makes sense??

Comment: If you print the query to screen rather than running it does the $pokemon_submit value have the expected value or is it blank?

It seems to me that the value that is coming in is not set... Also for safety sake you may want to look at expanding your check to if (isset($_POST['pokemon_submit'"]) && !empty($_POST['pokemon_submit'])) {

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to look at the other comments. Your querying looks fundamentally unsafe. However, I believe that your actual issue is here:

```
if (isset($_POST['pokemon_submit'])) {
    $pokemon_submit = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['submit']);
```

First, you look for `$_POST['pokemon_submit']`, but when you clean the string, you use `$_POST['submit']`.